# In angular material design, what is the effective position class when there are few?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design

I see this markup i my angular application:

```
<div class="m-b-10 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
```

what does it mean when there are few css classes that effects html positioning?

`col-md-5` tells the item to be positioned in medium col number 5

`col-xs-12` tells the item to be positioned in extra small col number 12

How do they combine?

Comment: I present you https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/ I don't know if your project is using v4 or v3